# Confused about protected member behaviour in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I am currently going through SCJP study guide. In chapter #1 page #36, its mentioned as:

> Once the subclass-outside-the-package inherits the protected member,
>   that member (as inherited by the subclass) becomes private to any code outside
>   the subclass, with the exception of subclasses of the subclass. So if class Neighbor
>   instantiates a Child object, then even if class Neighbor is in the same package as
>   class Child, class Neighbor won't have access to the Child's inherited (but protected)
>   variable x.

But whenever I'm trying to check that by following code:

```
    //parent class in pkg#1:
    package com.main.parentPkg;
    public class ParentInSamePkg {
     protected void methodInParent(){
       System.out.println("Inside ParentInSamePkg-->methodInParent");
     }
    }

    // First child class in pkg#2
    package com.main.childPkg;
    import com.main.parentPkg.ParentInSamePkg;
    public class ChildInOtherPkg extends ParentInSamePkg{
        void mthd(){
            System.out.println("inside ChildInOtherPkg:mthd");
            methodInParent();
        }
    }

    //Child class of child class inside pkg#3
    package com.main.grandChildPkg;
    import com.main.childPkg.ChildInOtherPkg;
    class GrandChild extends ChildInOtherPkg{
        void mthd(){
            System.out.println("inside GrandChild:mthd");
            methodInParent();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            GrandChild g=new GrandChild();
            g.mthd();
        }
    }
```

Whenever I'm executing above code and runs main method of GrandChild class, it prints output as:

```
inside GrandChild:mthd
Inside ParentInSamePkg-->methodInParent
```

Because of this, I am confused. As per concept, protected member became private after inheritance in child class and any class who extend this child class can't access this member. But in above code, it is accessible.

Please help me to understand.

Comment: You missed the significance of the clause _"with the exception of subclasses of the subclass"_.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: What's that?

Comment: Classes that extends the child class still sees the `protected` members of the parent class. That's because they are "subclasses of the subclass" and the `protected` members do not "become private" for to the child class as far as the child-of-child classes are concerned; the members remain `protected` for them.

Comment: @TedHopp: Thank a lotTed :-) I understood the concept very well. It means `protected` member will remain accessible and remain `protected` till inheritance tree continues. If I try to access the protected member of child class in non-child class i.e. without extending child class and creating child class object, it becames `private`.

Comment: Exactly. In my view, the wording in the study guide is confusing, although it was meant to clarify another point of potential confusion: normally, `protected` members are accessible to any code in the same package, even non-child classes. However, `protected` members of a parent class from a different package from the child class are not accessible to non-inheriting classes of the child's package (although they are accessible to sub-classes of the child). In that sense they behave as if they were `private`.

Answer (score 2):

Below table clearly describe the behavior of all types of access modifier.[image]

In case of protected ,it inaccessible only by Non-subclass present in the different package .We can say that **protected act like private** if and if only they are accessed by Non-subclass present in the different package.

Answer (score 0):

The entire concept of "protected member [...] becomes private" sounds weird.

Although the Java Language Specification is often very obscure to read, it actually says it well:

> **[6.6.2. Details on protected Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2)**
>
> A `protected` member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.

The important part is the **responsible for the implementation** part. All sub-classes, sub-sub-classes, sub-sub-sub-classes, ... are responsible for the implementation of the object, so they can all access the member.

This is regardless of whether it is its own instance (`this`) or another instance, as long as it's an instance of the class containing the code.

Or, as the JLS goes on to say:

> **[6.6.2.1. Access to a `protected` Member](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1)**
>
> Let C be the class in which a `protected` member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> In addition, if *Id* denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> - If the access is by a qualified name `Q.Id`, where `Q` is an *ExpressionName*, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of the expression `Q` is `S` or a subclass of `S`.
> - If the access is by a field access expression `E.Id`, where `E` is a *Primary* expression, or by a method invocation expression `E.Id(. . .)`, where `E` is a *Primary* expression, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of `E` is `S` or a subclass of `S`.